# i have 40401 by 57 matrix I need find max value from each row and the corresponding column index of that max value?

Tags: matlab

i have 40401 by 57 matrix I need to  find max value from each row and the corresponding column index of that max value?

some one please help me to find the answer..

Comment: Welcome to SO. This would be a better question if you explain what you have tried already. Why is the size of the matrix relevant to the question? Can you add a code example?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of the `max`-function. There is an example doing what you want. To find the documentation, use `doc max`.

Comment: if my matrix is A = [1 2 5;4 5 6;7 8 9;2 6 7] from each row i need to extract the maximum value and the corresponding column index . like for first row of matrix A , 5 is the max value and its corresponding column index is 3

Comment: You really need to read the documentation.  It clearly answers the question for you: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html?refresh=true#bupr490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by looking in the documentation we can find the syntax of `max` to find the maximum of `A` over a given dimension `dim`. There is even an example [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html?refresh=true#bupr490).

```
M = max(A,[],dim)
```

<sup>Note that the second argument is an empty matrix `[]` because we don't want to calculate the maximum of the entries in `A` and the second argument. This is another feature of `max` which has no relevance here.</sup>

Now we just need to get the indexes. Looking again in the documentation we find the syntax to get maximum values `M` and indexes `I` at the same time. There is an example [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html?refresh=true#bupr8_p) as well.

```
[M,I] = max(___)
```

<sup>Note that here `___` means that the syntax does not depend on the input values.</sup>

---

**Now we can combine this to the following line of code:**

```
[M,I] = max(A,[],2)
```

*This is the result when used with some random data:*

```
A =
     2    20     6     8     5    13
    16    11    10     2    10    20
     9    11    14     6    19     5
    15     2    17    19     1    11
M =
    20
    20
    19
    19
I =
     2
     6
     5
     4
```